# how to creat php function to edit config.php

Tags: php, fopen

In a project, I need to load some basic config without database query,  how to creat a function to edit this file.

config.php may like this:

```
 <?php 
define(DEBUG, TRUE);    
define (LANG, 'en');
define(THEME, 'joy');                                                                    

define(DB_NAME, 'cms');
define(DB_USER, 'root');
define(DB_PASSWORD, '000');
define(DB_HOST, 'localhost');

define(CACHE, '3600');
define(CLOSE, TRUE);
.....

ajax.php

$key = $_POST['key'];
$value = $_POST['value'];

function change_config($key,$value){
  // how ?
}
```

if I want to change cache time,  I can run change_config('CACHE','1800')
if I want to change debug value, I can run change_config('DEBUG',false)

Comment: Do you want to rewrite it in the file (hardcore) or do you just want to change the value if you load it?

Comment: You could rewrite the file with file_put_contents http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php. What I would do though is use file_put_contents to make a config file and let your config.php load the values of the created file.

Comment: Why tag this with `fopen`?

Comment: @Rizier123   I just want to change the value

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen  I think 'fopen expert' may help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could always take the easy route and use `runkit_constant_redefine`

```
runkit_constant_redefine($key, $value);
```

But of course, constants were built to be static. Editing that file directly means properly sanitizing input, and rewriting the file from the top to bottom every time. If the file size doesn't change and nor does the constant value's length, then you can use fwrite to write at the exact block where it exists, but that's generally not a solution. That said, use a database. they're not hard to learn.

**Edit**

When I was referring to using a database, I was implying the settings other than the DB connection, which should be static, or should change using something like Environment Variables, not being edited manually.

Comment: He/She probably wants a database free solution because these are the configs to the database.

Comment: @Daan Yes I did, did you? "That said, use a database. they're not hard to learn." - "I need to load some basic config without database query"

Comment: @RobinRijkeboer Yes but that's not the part I mean. He's giving a database free solution.

Comment: @Daan I was commenting on the "That said, use a database. they're not hard to learn." but this is turning off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php

$key = $_POST['key'];
$value = $_POST['value'];

require_once 'config.php';

function change_config($key,$value){
    $newContent = "<?php \n
                    define(DEBUG, " . ($key == "DEBUG"?$value:DEBUG) . "); \n
                    define(LANG, '" . ($key == "LANG"?$value:LANG) . "'); \n
                    define(THEME, '" . ($key == "THEME"?$value:THEME) . "'); \n";

    file_put_contents('config.php', $newContent);

}
```

Your overwriting the file with the new content. We create an string wich will hold the content of the NEW config.php file. The `\n` are for new lines.

Then we go past all the define lines and put them in the string. For the value we use an [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Simply said, that's an if statement which will check if the key is corresponding the define where building. If so we will put the new value in it. If not, we will enter the OLD CONFIG.php value.